# Google Plus LoadFriends fail

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I downloaded the `play games unity plugin` from this link : https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

I am trying to import the plugin into my Unity project as of now and this is the current `MainGui.cs` code below:

```
Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {
    mWaitingForAuth = false;
    if (success) {
        mStatusText = "Welcome " + Social.localUser.userName + ","+Social.localUser.id;

        Social.localUser.LoadFriends((bool s) => {
            if(s) {
                foreach(IUserProfile p in Social.localUser.friends){
                    mStatusText += "\n" + p.id + "," + p.userName;
                }
                mStatusText += "\nLoadFriends success...";
            }
            else
                mStatusText += "\nLoadFriends fail...";
        });
    } else {
        mStatusText = "Authentication failed.";
    }
    Debug.Log (mStatusText);
});
```

When I run this, I always get `mStatusText` as "LoadFriends fail...". I am unable to understand what could be causing the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `LoadFriends()` is not yet implemented as you can see [here in the source.](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/d90e470f532149f2171bc5871d325531d3656ef9/source/PluginDev/Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesPlatform.cs#L575)